# Undefined vtable for a single-file program

Tags: c++, gcc, functor

I wrote the following minimal 'sandbox' code of functors.

```
#include<cstdio>

struct Functor {
    virtual void operator() ();
    virtual ~Functor() {}
};

template<class Class, class FPtr>
struct FunctorImpl : Functor {
    FunctorImpl( Class const *_obj, FPtr _fptr ) : obj(_obj), fptr(_fptr) {}
    virtual void operator() () { (obj->*fptr)(); }
    virtual ~FunctorImpl() {}
protected:
    Class const *obj;
    FPtr fptr;
};

template<class Class, class FPtr>
FunctorImpl<Class,FPtr> *make_Functor( Class const *obj, FPtr fptr ) {
    return new FunctorImpl<Class,FPtr>(obj,fptr);
}

struct FOO {
    void bar() const { printf("1\n"); }
    void bar2() const { printf("2\n"); }
};

int main()
{
    FOO f;
    Functor* f1 = make_Functor( &f, &FOO::bar );
    Functor* f2 = make_Functor( &f, &FOO::bar2 );
    (*f1)();
    (*f2)();
}
```

However when compiling I got the error (with gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140624 (Red Hat 4.8.3-1))

```
/tmp/cc4ayCAU.o: In function `Functor::~Functor()':
functor.cpp:(.text._ZN7FunctorD2Ev[_ZN7FunctorD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for Functor'
/tmp/cc4ayCAU.o: In function `Functor::Functor()':
functor.cpp:(.text._ZN7FunctorC2Ev[_ZN7FunctorC5Ev]+0xf): undefined reference to `vtable for Functor'
/tmp/cc4ayCAU.o:(.rodata._ZTI11FunctorImplI3FOOMS0_KFvvEE[_ZTI11FunctorImplI3FOOMS0_KFvvEE]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Functor'
```

How is this possible with only a single file to compile? What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: @shuttle87: Why would it need a constructor? There's nothing to initialise.

Comment: @MikeSeymour, looks like I misread the question. Deleting previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virtual functions that are not abstract (`=0`) require a body, even if they are never called. Either provide dummy body to `Functor::operator()` or make it an abstract function.

Comment: Got it. I forgot to add =0 at the end.

Comment: Yet then I have another question: why does not the compiler throw a more helpful error message like 'virtual function not defined'?

Comment: @Rainn That's a question for them ;)